# cut() function puts all data in a single interval

Tags: r

I'm trying to cut a data to do a frequency distribution but after cut, all the data is assingned to one interval

```
points <- 224 * 0:5
cut_data <- cut(rs$amount, points ,dig.lab = 10)
```

My rs$amount data:

```
integer64
 [1] 517  200  391  186  262  1020 791  124  437  238  896  212  144  529  523  190
```

And I get something like this

```
> cut_data
 [1] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224] (0,224]
[15] (0,224] (0,224]
Levels: (0,224] (224,448] (448,672] (672,896] (896,1120]
```

What do I do wrong

EDIT:

result of dput() on rs$amount

```
structure(c(2.55431938899924e-321, 9.88131291682493e-322, 1.93179667523927e-321, 
9.18962101264719e-322, 1.29445199210407e-321, 5.03946958758071e-321, 
3.90805925860426e-321, 6.12641400843146e-322, 2.15906687232625e-321, 
1.17587623710217e-321, 4.42682818673757e-321, 1.04741916918344e-321, 
7.11454530011395e-322, 2.61360726650019e-321, 2.58396332774972e-321, 
9.38724727098368e-322), class = "integer64")
```

EDIT2:

Casting rs$amount as numeric helped with the issue

```
cut_data <- cut(as.numeric(rs$amount),points,dig.lab = 10)
```

Comment: Pleause  learn to use `dput` way to provide the data,  it's better, i.e. . run `dput(rs$ammount)` then paste in your question.

Comment: @PeaceWang there you go, I have no idea why is it so small and why i doesn't show normally

Comment: Are you using the bit64 package?

Comment: The numbers from your `dput` are all almost 0 but you're splitting them into intervals of 224. What were you expecting to happen? Are you sure you're working with the correct data? Or is there some process going on that you didn't include in the question?

Comment: @camille I get the data from database, the "amount" data in query result in DB is bigint type, I thought it's alright because as you see at the beginning of the question the numbers seem normal

Comment: `integer64` comes from an external package `bit64`. It's not a native R type and thus cannot be processed by R's native functions. Sadly, that package does not provide either a `.bincode.integer64` or `cut.integer64`. If you must use any one of them, consider converting your numbers back to R's atomic integers by `as.integer` (the package defines a method `as.integer.integer64` so this is legit) and then performing whatever computation you want. Otherwise, you would have to write your own `cut.integer64` for this to work. @m3k_1

Comment: Your cut breaks (points) are a single value `224 * 0.5`.  If you want generate breaks from 224 at 0.5 intervals use the `seq` function.

Comment: @SteveM that's `0:5`, not `0.5`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have two alternatives: use `cut(as.numeric(vec),...)` or `findInterval`.

### as.numeric

If you are not concerned about hitting the theoretical precision loss when converting to `integer64` to `numeric` (it might be hard to find this happening), then you can convert to `numeric`:

```r
cut(as.numeric(vec), points ,dig.lab = 10)
#  [1] (448,672]  (0,224]    (224,448]  (0,224]    (224,448]  (896,1120] (672,896]  (0,224]    (224,448]  (224,448]  (672,896]  (0,224]    (0,224]    (448,672]  (448,672]  (0,224]   
# Levels: (0,224] (224,448] (448,672] (672,896] (896,1120]
```

### findInterval

```r
table(cut(vec, points ,dig.lab = 10))
#    (0,224]  (224,448]  (448,672]  (672,896] (896,1120] 
#         16          0          0          0          0 
table(findInterval(vec, points))
# 1 2 3 4 5 
# 6 4 3 1 2
```

You can mock this to produce similarly-formatted factors manually:

```r
labels <- sprintf("(%i,%i]", points[-length(points)], points[-1])
labels
# [1] "(0,224]"    "(224,448]"  "(448,672]"  "(672,896]"  "(896,1120]"
factor(labels[findInterval(vec, points)], labels = labels)
#  [1] (448,672]  (0,224]    (224,448]  (0,224]    (224,448]  (896,1120] (672,896]  (0,224]    (224,448]  (224,448]  (896,1120] (0,224]    (0,224]    (448,672]  (448,672]  (0,224]   
# Levels: (0,224] (224,448] (448,672] (672,896] (896,1120]
```

---

Data

```r
vec <- structure(c(2.55431938899924e-321, 9.88131291682493e-322, 1.93179667523927e-321, 9.18962101264719e-322, 1.29445199210407e-321, 5.03946958758071e-321, 3.90805925860426e-321, 6.12641400843146e-322, 2.15906687232625e-321, 1.17587623710217e-321, 4.42682818673757e-321, 1.04741916918344e-321, 7.11454530011395e-322, 2.61360726650019e-321, 2.58396332774972e-321, 9.38724727098368e-322), class = "integer64")
```